# issue with api on https://newsapi.org/docs console log works but the render does not

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to include the API on newsapi.org/docs to my project , the get request works and it shows the result in the console log but not on the ejs page .

```js
 import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const API_URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla";
const APIKEY ="&apiKey=7160918468a64df9a7bf26e5915c1f50";
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs");
});
 
 app.get("/apiKey", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(API_URL + APIKEY);
      const result = response.data;
      console.log(result);
      res.render("index.ejs", { content: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).send(error.message);
    }
  });


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
  });


<body>

<div class="container col-7">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    <a href="/apiKey" class="btn btn-primary pill-rounded">Get All The NEWs</a> </div>
 


    
    </div>
<div class="col-8">
    <%if (locals.data) {%><div class="img-fluid text-center mt-5">
     <textarea  style="border: black; border-style: solid; width:530px; height:150px ;margin-top: 10px;" readonly>
<%= content.articles %>
        </textarea>
       </div>
        <%}%>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to display the result in the ejs file . i'm not sure what im doing wrong .

Comment: If the API key is your actual API key, maybe you should remove it from the question.